# Get Certain Tags Within Parent Tag Using Beautifulsoup4

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am using beautifulsoup4 with Python to scrape content from the web, with which I am attempting to extract content from specific html tags, while ignoring others.

I have the following html:

```
<div class="the-one-i-want">
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <div class="random-inserted-element-i-dont-want">
        <content>
    </div>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
</div>
```

My goal is to understand how to instruct python to only get the `<p>` elements from within the parent `<div> class="the-one-i-want">`, otherwise ignoring all the `<div>`'s within.

Currently, I am locating the content of the parent div by the following method:

```
content = soup.find('div', class_='the-one-i-want')
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to further specify to only extract the `<p>` tags from that without error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
h = """<div class="the-one-i-want">
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <div class="random-inserted-element-i-dont-want">
        <content>
    </div>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
    <p>
        "random text content here and about"
    </p>
</div>"""
```

You can just use `find_all("p")` after you find:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
soup = BeautifulSoup(h)

print(soup.find("div","the-one-i-want").find_all("p"))
```

Or use a css select:

```
print(soup.select("div.the-one-i-want p"))
```

Both will give you:

```
[<p>\n        "random text content here and about"\n    </p>, <p>\n        "random text content here and about"\n    </p>, <p>\n        "random text content here and about"\n    </p>, <p>\n        "random text content here and about"\n    </p>, <p>\n        "random text content here and about"\n    </p>]
```

*`find_all`* will only find descendants of the div with the class *`the-one-i-want`*, the same applies to our *`select`*

Comment: I swear I had tried that already, but I guess not. Problem solved. Thanks